# import Vue.js in a project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm-install, npm-init

How can i import Vue.js in VsCode on existing project? I don't want to create a new project.I already have installed node.js also.

I allready have node.js and i tried with npm install -g vue-cli  in the terminal it's installed but my app still doesn't work. It shows error in the console "Vue is not recognized". And also  i have vue.js devtools on my browser and it's not detected when i open my app.

My code in my js file:

```
const upvoteApp = {};
Vue.createApp(upvoteApp).mount("#app");
```

> error: Vue is not recognized;

Comment: [vue-cli](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/) is the old build tool for scaffolding vue 2 projects...  you just want vue so `npm install vue`.  It's not clear what the architecture is like for the rest of your app, if you have a package.json file, if you have a build step and whether you have vite or webpack, etc. If you're looking for simplest Vue application without a build step you can just use the [CDN](https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html#using-vue-from-cdn)